# error ruby "TypeError - can't dup Symbol" in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

have issue with code that rise just now but work before
i got this code:

1. Controller

   ```
   def new
   errors ||= Array.new
   if params[:file].blank? 
     errors.push(I18n.t("errors.messages.file_error"))
   end
   if errors.length == 0 
    # begin
    # 
     binding.pry
       assetObject = Assets.new(:asset=>params[:file])
       assetObject.save!
       image = assetObject.asset.url(:small)
       imageExpBanner = assetObject.asset.url(:expBanner)
       data = OpenStruct.new({
         id: assetObject.id,
         uri: image,
         expBannerUri: imageExpBanner
       })
       @responseObject = OpenStruct.new({
         status: true,
         errors: [],
         code: API_CODE_ERRORS['Services']['Global']['success'],
         objectData: data
       })
       render :template => 'api/v1/general/assets/new' ,:handlers => [:rabl],:formats => [:json]
     #rescue => e
     #  binding.pry
     #  logger.error e
      # errors.push(I18n.t("errors.messages.file_size_error"))
     #  render :json => Api::Init.ShowErrorJson(API_CODE_ERRORS['Services']['Global']['file_size'],I18n.t("errors.messages.feelike.input_error"), errors).to_json
   # end
   else
     render :json => Api::Init.ShowErrorJson(API_CODE_ERRORS['Services']['Global']['formInputError'],I18n.t("errors.messages.feelike.input_error"), errors).to_json
   end
   ```

   end
2. Model

class Assets < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  attr_accessible :asset,:asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :asset_file_size

  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { 
    :small => "150x150>" ,
    :expBanner => "620x184",
    :expBigImage => "304X304",
    :expSmallImage => "148X148",
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/uploads/:style/:id/:hash.:extension",
    :url  => :s3_eu_url ,
    :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
    }
    validates :asset, :attachment_presence => true
  validates_attachment_size :asset, :less_than => 10.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type => ['image/jpeg','image/gif', 'image/png']
end
```

now its return me this error:

```
Started POST "/api/general/assets/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-28 11:32:19 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::General::AssetsController#new as JSON
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc39853ac10 @original_filename="usidentification.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"usidentification.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130328-15640-1hdj5ee>>}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3491ms

TypeError - can't dup Symbol:
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:176:in `block in styles'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:175:in `styles'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:421:in `post_process_styles'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:415:in `block (2 levels) in post_process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3148635882202100687__asset_post_process__2098004068316531280__callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_asset_post_process_callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:414:in `block in post_process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3148635882202100687__post_process__2098004068316531280__callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_post_process_callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:413:in `post_process'
  (gem) paperclip-3.4.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:108:in `assign'
```

now what dose it means TypeError - can't dup Symbol
now i try few ways fix at and got this every time need help in this

Comment: please could you post also your code tied with `has_attached_file` part of the code

Answer (score 0):

found the issue was there

```
 has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { 
    :small => "150x150>" ,
    :expBanner => "620x184",
    :expBigImage => "304X304",
    :expSmallImage => "148X148",
},
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/uploads/:style/:id/:hash.:extension",
    :url  => :s3_eu_url ,
    :hash_secret => "longSecretString"
```